# how can i detect when a google calendar event starts with google-apps-script script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to trigger a script every time a calendar event starts. Does anyone know if there a trigger for detecting this which i can bind to?

I'm open to doing this with any platform, not just google-apps-script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a script that pulls all the calendar details into a sheet, and then create a formula to check for the current time and chain the action from that. So the script could be this:

```
function calDataRetrival(){

//replace your.email with your actual Google account address
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('your.email@gmail.com');
//you also need a sheet with the same name as your email, so set that up first
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('your.email@gmail.com')
var today = new Date();

var events = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('your.email@gmail.com').getEventsForDay(today);
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {

var details=[[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getAllTagKeys()]];
var row=i+1;
var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,4);
range.setValues(details);
}
}
```

The above script pulls all the calendar entries into a sheet, then in that sheet you can compare the current time using '=NOW()' to pull the time into one cell and then compare it to the calendar entries using some thing like: =if($I$1>B1,1,0) where 'I1' contains =NOW() and B1 is the start time of the event.

Hope that helps.